# How to Count the number of occurrences for a group of rows and remove duplicated rows?

Tags: vba, count, duplicates, unique

I have a report where I need to find duplicated groups of rows defined by Column named Cut No and each time this group of rows repeated I have to count the number of its occurrence as 1,2,3 until any column data changes as follows:

```
Cut No     Length     BBS No                          BM     Quantity     Occurrences    
1          3300       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     39     2                
1          3200       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     952    1                
1          2125       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     77     1                  N

2          3300       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     39     2                
2          3200       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     952    1                
2          2125       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     77     1                  N + 1

3          3300       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     77     1
3          3200       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     952    1
3          2125     **2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0412-02**   77     1                  N + 1
```

The problem is that all codes works on a row level but in this case I am working on changing group of rows defined by cut No and the other four columns should be unique,

When I use Remove Duplicates using the Cut No, it says No Duplicates

And I use Remove Duplicates without using the Cut No, I get the following

```
 Length     BBS No                          BM     Quantity      
 3300       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     39     2                
 3200       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     952    1                
 2125       2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0411-02     77     1  
 2125     **2453-04-ST-RF-HA-FO-0412-02**   77     1
```

It gives unique rows But What I want Unique Group of Rows As Explained Above

So how I can do this When each group of rows matched with the next, the Number of Occurrences Increased by 1

Thanks your reply

Moheb Labib

Comment: How Do I use Dictionary  to read group of data adjacent to each Cut No?

Answer (score 0):

Use subtotals. Select your table and Data -> Subtotal and selec the colums you want subtotals of:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) I understand you well, then maybe a quick solution to your problem would be simpy convert each group of rows into a single row having three times more columns e.g. in an additional sheet. Then you may simply work on rows instead of groups of rows.